# Parse and Display HTML in a QTextEdit widget

Tags: python, html, qt, qtextedit

I have a non-editable QTextEdit Widget in one of my apps. Basend on the selection of a combobox i want to display additional informations.

My current approach is to load HTML files from a directory and display them in the QTextEdit-Field. This sounds easy (with the functions setHtml or insertHtml), but somehow doesn't work as straight forward as i thought. I believe i have to parse or load in the file first. How can i continue?

```
h = (helpdir + str + ".html") # contains the helpfiles path (Format QString)
# Load in HTML?
textfield.insertHtml(h) # Should somehow insert the html
```

Other approaches (especially in the light of a future translation of the help), which are easy to implement, are welcome. I would favor any solution without additional libraries or non base packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have to load the HTML file before inserting it into the `QTextEdit`. But doing it is pretty easy:

```
    f = QFile("path/to/your/htmlfile")
    f.open(QFile.ReadOnly|QFile.Text)
    istream = QTextStream(f)
    textfield.setHtml(istream.readAll())
    f.close()
```

It works just fine (assuming that your HTML file is not very large). You can also read the file line by line if it fits better your needs.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [QtWebKit](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/QtWebKit) it's the best way to go with html content in qt. It should come with your python qt install. check out the code below:

**test.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
view = QtWebKit.QWebView()
view.setHtml(open('test.html').read())
window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
window.setCentralWidget(view)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**test.html**

```
<html><body><h1>test page</h1>testing...</body></html>
```

Comment: This is indeed an overkilling solution if you just want to display some html text into a textedit. `QtWebKit` is a whole web browser engine.